# Middleware Terminate Function Not Executing in 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, middleware

I have a middleware that is used to log requests in the Database. The log is initially created when the request comes in in the `handle()` method. I am now trying to add a `terminate()` method that will add the response status to log. However the `terminate()` method does not seem to be getting called.

I have it registered in the `routeMiddleware` in `Kernel.php` (the handle function runs properly). It is also being applied to a group of routes, with the handle function executing properly. It just seems that the terminate function will not execute.

Here is the terminate function:

```
public function terminate($request, $response)
{
    $log = Audit::find(Request::get('AUDIT-LOG-ID'));

    $log->status = $response->status();

    $log->save();
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

I deliberately added bugs into the `terminate` function that would cause a server error. However they were never executed and requests went through as normal, I believe this confirms my hunch that the `terminate` function is not being executed.

Comment: call the logger in the `terminate` method, then you will actually know, as you will have something written to the log

Comment: @lagbox Sorry for the late reply, I have tried calling the logger and nothing is logged.